# convert cupy to numpy is very slow

Tags: numpy, cupy

## Condition

- CuPy version
  7.0.0
- OS/Platform
  Ubuntu 18.04
- CUDA version
  10.1

## Code to reproduce

```py
import cupy as np
import time
size = 60000000
tag = np.zeros(size)
#np.random.shuffle(tag)
value = np.random.random(size)
starttime = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(100):
    tag +=(value> 0.3)*100
print (time.perf_counter() - starttime)
starttime = time.perf_counter()
cpu_value = np.asnumpy(value)
print (time.perf_counter() - starttime)
```

- convert cupy to numpy is very slow
  The result is

  > 0.02095769099832978 
  >   6.170492547998947

Answer (score 1):

Converting from CuPy to NumPy involves doing a copy from the GPU memory to the CPU.
This operation is expensive and is expected to be slow. Ideally, you want your data to live in the GPU as long as possible and only move it to the CPU when it is strictly necessary.